# Hiding Floating action button when parent scrolled

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm creating a custom `FAB` button for both `android` and `iOS` platforms using `Xamarin.Forms`.

Everything is working fine, but now I want to be able to somehow receive `scrolled` events from the nearest parent of the `FAB` button if any, so I will be able to hide the `FAB` button when the user is scrolling and then show it again after 2 seconds of scrolling finished?.

The parent could be a plain `ScrollView` item, or it could be a `ListView`.
Can this be achieved via the same custom renderers for each platform? Or, can this even be achieved at all?

This is what I did so far:

1. `FabButton` class:

```
public partial class FabButton : Button
{
    public static BindableProperty ButtonColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ButtonColor), typeof(Color), typeof(FabButton), Color.Accent);
    public Color ButtonColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(ButtonColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonColorProperty, value);
    }
    public FabButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

2. `iOS` custom renderer:

   ```
   public class FabButtonRenderer:ButtonRenderer
   {
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           if(e.NewElement == null)
               return;
           if (Element.WidthRequest <= 0)
               Element.WidthRequest = 60;
           if (Element.HeightRequest <= 0)
               Element.HeightRequest = 60;
           if (Element.Margin == new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0))
               Element.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 20, 20);
           Element.CornerRadius = (int) Element.WidthRequest / 2;
           Element.BorderWidth = 0;
           Element.Text = null;
           Control.BackgroundColor = ((FabButton) Element).ButtonColor.ToUIColor();
       }
       public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
       {
           base.Draw(rect);
           Layer.ShadowRadius = 0.2f;
           Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
           Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(1, 1);
           Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.80f;
           Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromOval(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
           Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
       }
       protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
           if (e.PropertyName == nameof(FabButton.ButtonColor))
               Control.BackgroundColor = ((FabButton) Element).ButtonColor.ToUIColor();
       }
   }
   ```
3. `android` custom renderer:

   ```
   public class FabButtonRenderer: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ViewRenderer<FabButton,FloatingActionButton>
   {
       public static void InitRenderer() { }
       public FabButtonRenderer(Context context):base(context)
       {

       }

       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FabButton> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           if (e.NewElement == null)
               return;
           if (e.NewElement.HeightRequest <= 0)
               e.NewElement.HeightRequest = 85;
           if (e.NewElement.WidthRequest <= 0)
               e.NewElement.WidthRequest = 75;
           if (e.NewElement.Margin.Equals(new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)))
               e.NewElement.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 10);
           var fabButton = new FloatingActionButton(Context);
           ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(fabButton, ColorStateList.ValueOf(Element.ButtonColor.ToAndroid()));
           fabButton.UseCompatPadding = true;
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Image?.File))
               fabButton.SetImageDrawable(Context.GetDrawable(Element.Image.File));
           fabButton.Click += FabButton_Clicked;
           SetNativeControl(fabButton);
       }

       protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
       {
           base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
           Control.BringToFront();
       }

       protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.ButtonColor))
               ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(Control, ColorStateList.ValueOf(Element.ButtonColor.ToAndroid()));
           if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.Image))
           {
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Image?.File))
                   Control.SetImageDrawable(Context.GetDrawable(Element.Image.File));
           }
           base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
       }

       public void FabButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Element.SendClicked();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `built-in` way to do this.
Since in my case, the `Floating Action Button` might be affected by `ScrollView` control scrolling, or a list view control scrolling, or others.
The only way for me to do this that I can think of is to specify explicitly to which `ScrollView` control the `Floating Action Button` should be connected, and since this will be a troublesome to implement when the `Floating Action Button` should be connected to a list view `ScrollView` and since it's better to use the `MVVM` pattern, I have find a simpler way to this.
First I declared an interface `IFloatingActionButtonHost`:

```
public interface IFloatingActionButtonHost
{
    bool ShouldBeHiddenWhenScrolling { get; }
    event Action LinkedScrollViewScrolled;
}
```

And then, I declared a `BindableProperty` inside the `FabButton` control like this:

```
public static BindableProperty ButtonHostProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ButtonHost), typeof(IFloatingActionButtonHost), typeof(FabButton));
public IFloatingActionButtonHost ButtonHost
{
    get => (IFloatingActionButtonHost)GetValue(ButtonHostProperty);
    set => SetValue(ButtonHostProperty, value);
}
```

And in the `Renderer` for example, on `iOS` renderer, I checked for this property if it's not null, and if the `Floating Action Button` *should* be hidden when the target `ScrollView` get scrolled or not and then subscribed to the event in the interface.

```
    var fabButton = (FabButton)Element;
    if (fabButton.ButtonHost != null && fabButton.ButtonHost.ShouldBeHiddenWhenScrolling)
    {
        fabButton.ButtonHost.LinkedScrollViewScrolled += OnLinkedScrollView_Scrolled;
    }
```

And then I handled the event in the renderer:

```
private void OnLinkedScrollView_Scrolled()
{
    Element.IsVisible = false;
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
    {
        if(Element != null){
            Element.IsVisible = true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

The `OnElementPropertyChanged` implementation should be changed as well.

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(FabButton.ButtonColor))
        Control.BackgroundColor = ((FabButton) Element).ButtonColor.ToUIColor();
    else if(e.PropertyName == nameof(FabButton.ButtonHost)){
        var fabButton = (FabButton)Element;
        if (fabButton.ButtonHost != null && fabButton.ButtonHost.ShouldBeHiddenWhenScrolling)
        {
            fabButton.ButtonHost.LinkedScrollViewScrolled += OnLinkedScrollView_Scrolled;
        }
    }
}
```

On Each page `code-behind`, I make the page inherit form this interface, and just passed the page instance to the target `ViewModel`.
**P.S.** For `ListView` I had to write a custom renderer to expose the `Scrolled` event. Sorry, I haven't find a better way to do this.
This is my attempt to solve this problem, if you have a better solution, please just **write another answer to this question** and I will mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think Scrollview's "Scrolled" event can help you , you will get X & Y axis values , based on it you have to hide your fab button while it's scrolling.
And for it after 2 seconds you can use "Device.StartTimer" .

Comment: It doesn't work like this. Obviously, I don't know if there is a separate `ScrollView` control in the page's elements tree or not, so I need to traverse up the elements tree and find out if the current `parent` has a `ScrollView` or not and then maybe subscribe to that `Scrolled` event.

Comment: if parent is listview https://github.com/velocitysystems/xf-controls this can help you

Comment: Sorry mate, but your answer didn't help me in my specific situation but +1 for the `ListView` custom renderer reference.